# MVC3 - Coding a custom HTML Helper which output works with unobtrusive Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I am attempting to add unobtrusive JavaScript to a file upload input control, using a custom HTML Helper extension. However, I have checked various blogs which use different methods to create the control, such as tab-builder but I couldn't find out how the unobtrusive data tags are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unobtrusive data tags mainly means using the [HTML 5 extensible "data-" attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Check this blog post of Brad Wilson about [unobtrusive javascript in MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html), he describes the various attributes used by the unobtrusive framework.

Comment: How do I get the validation function to call? For example, the required attribute will add data-val-required to the input. When building my own custom HtmlHelper, how do I know what attribute has been set on the input?

Comment: @Extrakun - Won't you be setting it yourself using the Tag Builder? Maybe I'm not following completely, have you started on some code that you can show?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TagBuilder, you can do this:

```
var validationAttributes = html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata);
```

then use MergeAttributes on your tagbuilder to add the unobtrusive validation attributes to your tag.